# Load chrome extension script when twitter stream loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, google-chrome-extension

I just wrote a chrome extension that replaces stock symbols designted with a $ before them with data from yahoo finance. I am running into some issues though based on how twitter loads the stream. I have the js set to run on document_end but twitter loads the stream after the DOM is ready. To get around this I just checked to see if a certain Element existed and then ran the scripts if it didnt just wait 500 ms and try again.

There seems to be an issue on the search pages as well possibly because the element I am checking has a different class I did not really look into the issue yet.

The other issue is it creates a mess when there are tons of symbols in one tweet might be related to the first issue but seems like it is inserting extra DOM elements.

the project is hosted on github would be awesome to get some feedback and possibly contributions.

https://github.com/billpull/Twitter-Ticker

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to listen to DOMMutation events. Before the browser renders the tweet, you can capture this with `DOMNodeInserted` event.

As Chrome 18, `MutationObservers` are now implemented, it is fast, and doesn't fire to quickly so it is concise. DOM Mutation Observers is asynchronous and can fire multiple changes per call! It significantly improves performance of your mutations.

An example of using `MutationObservers` would be:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function onMutationObserver(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutationNode) {
    // New Nodes added ... Deal with it!
  });
});
observer.observe(historyContainerDOM, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

I have added some comments to one of my [open source extensions](https://github.com/mohamedmansour/accessible-hangouts-extension/blob/master/js/accessible_hangouts_injection.js) that talk about this, feel free to take what you want.